# EasyUI datagrid Sorting

Tags: jquery, datagrid, jquery-easyui

I am using datagrid with server-side pagination. When user navigate to a certain page "n" and clicks on an column to sort, the sorted result is displayed but the page is "n".

Is it possible  show the sorted result with page as 1.

Comment: please provide the link of your plugin

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether there is a better solution, but you could try adding an event on the column headers, so when the user clicks on them he/she is moved to page 1. Try the following:

```
$(".datagrid-header-row td").click(function(){
   $('#gridId .pagination').pagination('select', 1);
});
```